# Ubuntu One stuck at "File Sync Starting" on Lubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu-one

I installed Ubuntu One on my Lubuntu installation, and it's not syncing my files or folders. When I open the control panel, it says "File Sync Starting" in the upper-right hand corner. And I can select folders to sync without any issues.  But nothing gets synced.

One of the other "suggested questions" mentioned that it's slow. But, this has been going for about 24 hours now (not counting the days that I've had it running before).  I've tried installing EVERYTHING that came with "sudo apt-get install ubuntuone*" and that didn't fix the issue.  Now, I've uninstalled everything, and installed ubuntuone-control-panel-qt along with it's associated dependencies.

On February 16, I sent an email to UbuntuOne support and haven't received anything back. So I'm asking for suggestions here. I really don't want to have to install ubuntu-desktop--just to get Ubuntu One working.

One other issue (not related) that I could add is that my hard drive does have occasional Input/Output errors. BUT this problem was happening on another drive which has no issues (I copied the entire drive over to this one)--so that's not the cause of this issue.

As an edit/update to this, I ran u1sdtool --status (per another thread), and here are the results:

```
patrickdickey@dcky-ubuntu64:~$u1sdtool --status
State: LOCAL_RESCAN
    connection: With User With Network
    description: doing local rescan
    is_connected: False
    is_error: False
    is_online: False
    queues: WORKING
```

Thanks for any suggestions, and have a great day.:)
Patrick.